# How to get flutter_map's MapController() stream events? Flutter

Tags: flutter, fluttermap

I'm trying to listen for `MapEvents` from `MapController()`as suggested here https://github.com/fleaflet/flutter_map/issues/877#issuecomment-825545206 as

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _mapController.mapEventStream.where((event) => event is MapEventMoveEnd).listen((event) {
      // TODO: You code
    });
  }
```

the problem is that I don't have `mapEventStream` available option in `_mapController`.
Is it just a package version problem or what am I doing wrong??
I'm still using flutter_map: ^0.10.1 as I'd have to update many other packages..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your package version is too old to make use of that feature. You need at least **0.11.0** to use `mapEventStream`, though you may be able to get away with **0.10.1+1** depending on your use case.

Looking at the [commit history](https://github.com/fleaflet/flutter_map/commits/master/lib/src/map/map.dart) for lib/src/map/map.dart (the file with MapController code), two commits are of interest:

- [July 9, 2020](https://github.com/fleaflet/flutter_map/commit/85558c9194f0f0b7b1f7b20e6d487d8fdfe523fb#diff-d218fbadf1cf8a3f0cd4f273f5309122a5564e89652bcc4088c6ccdf5b591fd4): on line 62, a `MapPosition` stream called `position` was added.
- [Jan 29, 2021](https://github.com/fleaflet/flutter_map/commit/d6b365ed7228da1e85bdbe3b19b20b313af20b81#diff-d218fbadf1cf8a3f0cd4f273f5309122a5564e89652bcc4088c6ccdf5b591fd4): also on line 62 `position` is changed to `mapEventStream` and its stream type changed to emit `MapEvent` objects.

Looking now at the flutter_map [version history](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_map/versions), the earliest version that includes the first commit mentioned above is 0.10.1+1, and to get the latter form you need 0.11.0.

I have tested the existence of both getters in their respective versions in my editor.

Comment: welcome to this great dev community. Thanks, I knew the problem would be the older version I'm currently using. I guess it's time to update all dependencies.. quite a pain in the butt but hey..
Many thanks again for taking the time too go through the commits and find the min version I should use, really appreciate it. Cheers.